# Python terminal in html?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

You can downvote this before you read (Edit:Thank you for understanding) because of the title but other questions just answers how to run python programs in html but what I want to do is use python terminal in html.

So guys there is actually big big question in my head. How exactly can I use python program in html like it is a terminal.

Here is my project, it will be an interactive dictionary that you can study on vocabulary.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
    font-family: Arial
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* The browser window */
.container {
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

/* Container for columns and the top "toolbar" */
.row {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.scriptcontainer {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.row2 {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #cc0000;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

/* Create three unequal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
}

.left {
    width: 15%;
}

.right {
    width: 10%;
}

.middle {
    width: 75%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Three dots */
.dot {
    margin-top: 4px;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Style the input field */
input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: -8px;
    height: 25px;
    color: #666;
    padding: 5px;
}



.bar {
    width: 17px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    margin: 3px 0;
    display: block;
}

/* Page content */
.content {
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="column middle">
        <h4><font size="6" type="Times">VocaDict</font></h4>
   </div>

  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h3>=>Your dictionary:</h3>
      <div class="row2"><div class="content"><div class="scriptcontainer">        <script>//This is where your dictionary will go!</script></div></div></div>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
    <h3>=>Study lists:</h3>
      <div class="row2"><div class="content"><div class="scriptcontainer">    <script>//This is where your dictionary will go!</script></div></div></div>
      </div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

What I'm asking is about this places:

```
<div class="content"><div class="scriptcontainer">    <script>//This is the place I want python terminal to be!</script>
```

I want this places act like a python terminal. When the page loads it will run the program, it will not affect any other thing and act like an independent thing but it will stay on the page and will be interactive.

Is that possible and If it is, how?

Thank you!

Comment: There are places on the web that offer Python (and other) REPLs. You could inspect those. I bet some of them even have github pages. Otherwise, this is much too broad for SO.

Comment: Nice profile picture Elvez. Unfortunetly, despite being a Don't Starve fan. I have tp agree theat this question does notbelong on SO, like @jdv has stated. Good luck and take care buddy!

Comment: Upon rereading this question it occurs to me that this might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), in that you are asking to solve an assumed problem, but we really don't know why. See [ask]. What do you want to do, what have you tried, and what results do you get?

Comment: @RannLifshitz Thanks but I don't understand why people always tell me my questions are not suitable with SO. I just get stuck and things I search on net and SO ussualy don't give me the right answer. So my only choice is to ask.

Comment: Elvez - as @jdv has stated, there is a dedicated thread on how to ask questions on SO  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Not complying with this standard will probably result in downvotes from other SO users. This is not personal, but rather an enforcement of a protocol which helps individuals from multiple nationalities communicate with one another. Best of luck buddy.

Comment: @RannLifshitz Thanks for your wishes, I read the terms a couple times but I still think it will take some time to use the forum fully efficient as SO mentioned at the end of the list : "It might take a few or more attempts to ask perfect questions."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do here exactly? If you really want to run python script with HTML then go for CGI. As you can't run python directly you may have to use the below,

```
http://karrigell.sourceforge.net/en/pythoninsidehtml.html
```

or

```
http://www.skulpt.org/
```

But best way would be to use python-cgi programming `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm`

Comment: I was really hoping someone would answer with a single sentence: "CGI."

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible.

I had this question myself before. Clearly the intention was make room for other scripts, at least I think this way:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/python">
```

It would require a browser that implements this. Maybe this engine: https://www.gnu.org/software/pythonwebkit/